# .htaccess rewriterule is not working in server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my .htaccess code,the below code is perfectly working in localhost.in localhost it leads me to a not found page (404).
my directory structure is www.mysite.com/shoppe/

```
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} main
RewriteRule   ^main/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   /shoppe/main.php?main_id=$1   [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sub
RewriteRule   ^sub/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   /shoppe/sub.php?category=$1   [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} product
RewriteRule   ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   /shoppe/product.php?pro_ids=$1   [L]
```

Comment: To clarify the question, Is your code works perfectly in local and not in web server? If so then you need to access the phpmyadmin in your hosting and upload the .htaccess file

Comment: yes .i did ,still not working